# "unescaped " character" when importing text data into SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to import a semicolon-separated text file where each line ends in CRLF. The first line contains the fields, and the data start at line 2:

```
"Field1";"Field2"
"123";"Foo"
"456";"Bar"
```

I tried the following, but it fails with "input.csv:23: unescaped " character":

```
sqlite3.exe
sqlite> .separator ";"
sqlite> .mode csv MyTable
sqlite> .import input.csv MyTable
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: And what is in line 23?

Comment: Just one of the records. I checked, there's nothing odd. Each field looks like the above, using double quotes before and after.

Comment: The `sqlite3` program thinks there's something odd.

Answer (score 7):

For sqlite, when the data to be imported may contain the double-quote character ("), do not use csv mode. The code that reads each CSV field [csv_read_one_field](https://github.com/sqlite/sqlite/blob/master/src/shell.c.in#L4986) looks for it and when it finds it, ensures that it is terminated or expects it to be quoted.

Changing the column separator to ';' won't help because that code will still be executed.

On the other hand, the code that reads each field in ascii mode [ascii_read_one_field](https://github.com/sqlite/sqlite/blob/master/src/shell.c.in#L5076) only uses the column and row separators to determine the field contents.

So, Use ascii mode and set the column and row separators to semi-colon and end of line like this:

*nix:

```
sqlite> .mode ascii
sqlite> .separator ";" "\n"
sqlite> .import input.csv MyTable
```

windows:

```
sqlite> .mode ascii
sqlite> .separator ";" "\r\n"
sqlite> .import input.csv MyTable
```

However, that will not strip out the double-quotes surrounding your data; they are considered part of your data.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Do you know if ascii mode can read in utf8 in the non-ascii range correctly?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
$ sqlite3 input.sqlite
sqlite>.mode csv
sqlite>.separator ;
sqlite>.import .input.csv input
```

which created the following schema

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE input(
"Field1" TEXT,
"Field2" TEXT
);
```

I had similar issues when trying to load a larger CSV file. In that case, csvsql (part of csvkit) did the trick

```
csvsql --db sqlite:///mydb.sqlite --insert input.csv
```

This approach had the added benefit of detecting the data types for each column.

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE input (
"Field1" DECIMAL NOT NULL,
"Field2" VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: The original question states, the error message is "input.csv:23: unescaped " character"
That means, line 23 is to be checked.
I have experienced such error if there were space present out of double quote:

    "123"; "Foo"